# R to optimize marketing strategy

Tags: r, optimization

I am new to R and I am trying to run an optimization function.
   I have 3 Variables:
   $Revenue
   $Spent on a tv campaign
   $Spent on a radio campaign

How do I optimize my budget allocation across tv and radio campaign?
in other words, how do I find the optimal spend for each individual driver

Comment: Ridiculously written question. Stop asking questions if you don't know what you even need..

Answer (score 0):

```
There are 3 characteristics of an optimization problem:
1.Decision Variables -The variables whose value is to be decided in order to achieve our objective
2.Objective Function – linear function of decision variables
3.Constraints – restrictions which cause hinderance in achieving the objective.
```

I think linear programming is the best way to illustrate this point.

```
require(lpSolveAPI)

model<-make.lp(ncol=4)
m1<-lp.control(model, sense="max", verbose="neutral")
m2<-set.objfn(model, obj=c(1/250,1/200,1/150,1/100))
m3<-set.bounds(model, lower=c(250000,200000,75000,50000))
m4<-add.constraint(model, c(1,1,0,0), "<=",600000)
m5<-add.constraint(model, c(1,1,1,1), type="<=",1000000)
m6<-add.constraint(model, c((1500/250-500/250),(800/200-500/200),(300/150-500/150),(100/100-500/100)), type=">=",0)


rownames=c("facebook & Adword budget constraint","total budget","LTV")
colnames=c("Adword","Facebook","Email","Affiliated")
dimnames(model)=list(rownames,colnames)
name.lp(model,"Maximize Number Of Users")
write.lp(model, filename="lp_model.lp")
kable(readLines("lp_model.lp"))


solve(model)
get.variables(model)
get.objective(model)
```

https://analyticsprofile.com/business-analytics/how-to-optimise-digital-marketing-spend-using-linear-programming-in-r/